# How to remove nested arrays with $pull

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a database in this structure

```
{
   "_id":"",
   "array1":[
      {
         "_id":"",
         "array2":[
            {
               
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to delete array2 by using _id and array._id with $pull, however im not having any success.

I tried updateOne like this but it doesn`t work

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$in":[
         id1,
         id2
      ]
   }
},
{
   "$pull":{
      "array1.$.array2":{
         "array1._id":{
            "$in":[
               id3,
               id4
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

i get the error "the positional operator did not find the match needed from the query". Does anyone know how can i approach this?

Comment: Are you trying to remove all elements from `"array2"`, or remove the field `"array2"` completely?

Comment: all elements from array2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements from an array and keep the field, you can just set the field's value to an empty array (`[]`).

Here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$in": [id1, id2]  // <-- document "_id"
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "array1.$[elem1].array2": []
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem1._id": {
        "$in": [id3, id4]  // <-- "_id" of array1 element
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PgsDtSLrEvp).

If you want to use `"$pull"`, you could do this, but I wouldn't expect it to be as efficient.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$in": [id1, id2]
  }
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "array1.$[elem1].array2": {
      "$exists": true
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem1._id": {
        "$in": [id3, id4]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpGaIowHqxq).